# Check if NSString exists in custom object in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` with `Store` objects. Each `Store` object has two `NSString` objects; `StoreID` and `Name`.
I would like to check quickly if an ID exists in this `NSArray` with `Store` objects.

Example:

```
Store *s1 = [[Store alloc] init];
s1.name = @"Some Name";
s1.id = @"123ABC";

Store *s2 = [[Store alloc] init];
s2.name = @"Some Other Name";
s2.id = @"ABC123";

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:s1, s2, nil];

NSString *myIdOne = @"ABCDEF";
NSString *myIdTwo = @"123ABC";

BOOL myIdOneExists = ...?
BOOL myIdTwoExists = ...?
```

Its the `...?` I need to figure out. I know I can do this using a `for` loop and break when found... but this seems to me like an nasty approach since the `NSArray` could contain thousands of objects,... theoretically. 
So I would like to know about a better solution.

Comment: Do you think that the system has some magical way to look through array entries without having to just do one at a time?

Comment: @Pfitz -- I didn't know a BOOL was an object.

Comment: @Pfitz -- The array doesn't contain `@"ABCDEF` either.

Comment: From the doc: `Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object is present in the array.`. The given object `myIdOne` will not be present in `array`, however it will be in `s1`. Thats the thing. I would like to know if there is an `Store` object containing `id` as `myIdOne`.

Comment: @Pfitz - That's not puzzling at all.  As I said, `@"ABCDEF"` is not in the array.

Comment: I must say, eventhough there were some trigger-happy condescending repliers, it still was harder then some expected.

Comment: If you make a string by joining components of that array you can check the range of id string in that string.. I don't know its a good method or not..

Comment: @Anusha - Gets a bit messy if the IDs are not all the same length.  Searching for "BCD" would find "ABCD", "ABCDE", "BCDE", etc.  (But I confess to using this technique (with sentinels) in other contexts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",@"id", myID];
NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if (filteredArray.count > 0)
  Store *store = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Of course, that scheme will iterate through all the array elements, even if the "answer" is found in the second one.

Comment: Of course you could use fast enumeration, do the search yourself and stop when finding the store you are searching for, but if the array is small enough, this solution should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. My guess is that the array will at most contain up to about 200 objects... would you still suggest your solution?

Comment: Ok. Then I think your solution is the one to go with... or a for loop that break on result found which, with regards to memory usage still seems smarter, right?

Comment: The third line should be if (**filteredArray**.count > 0).  Or you can just use `Store *store = [filteredArray lastObject];` since this returns `nil` instead of crashing if there are no objects. (This assumes filteredArray will only ever have 1 object).

Comment: @tilo, It should be **`if (filteredArray.count > 0)`** and not **`if (array.count > 0)`**. This code will crash if `filteredArray `count is zero.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the thing: No matter what solution you go with, it will more or less boil down to "loop over the array and return whether or not the object was found." There is no way to search an array more quickly than this unless very specific conditions are met (e.g. the array is already sorted by the value you're searching). You can use a predicate, you can use an enumerator, you can use fast enumeration or you can use a test block — under the hood, they all amount to "loop over the array and perform a test." That's just how arrays work.

If this is something you need to do often and performance is a problem with the naive solution, a sensible solution might be to cache your IDs in an NSSet. Sets are tuned for fast member detection, so you should be able to get your answer much more quickly than you could with an array.

My personal "loop-over-the-array" solution:

```
BOOL idExists = NSNotFound != [stores indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(Store *store, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [store.id isEqualToString:@"whatever"];
}];
```

(Written in the browser, so, y'know, caveat compilor.)

Comment: Yep, you made the point better than I could that, no matter what, you're iterating over all elements.  The twin goals should be to do it efficiently (only once, and with minimal additional object creation) and to do it in an "obvious" manner that is sufficiently "obvious" to be maintainable and unlikely to contain subtle bugs.  (I wish "indexOfObjectPassingTest" had come to mind -- I've maybe used it once, so it's not familiar to me.)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution, just use KVC:

```
NSArray *results = [array valueForKey:@"id"];
BOOL myIdOneExists = [results containsObject:myIdOne];
BOOL myIdTwoExists = [results containsObject:myIdTwo];
```

Comment: So you'd construct an array of all 10 thousand IDs in order to see if one of them matches??

Comment: It is a good idea, however like @HotLicks implies it does create a large memory usage if the array is 10k of objects in size.

Comment: @HotLicks No, he'd be creating an array containing *references* to all 10 thousand IDs. (Perhaps that wouldn't be much smaller, but still...)

Comment: @trudyscousin -- The array must be allocated and populated.  Lots of motion to save 3 lines of source code.

Comment: I agree, using a NSPredicate in most cases would be more **efficient**. I just gave the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL) id:(NSString*) theId existsInArray:(NSArray*) theArray {
    for (Store* theStore in theArray) {
        if ([theStore.id isEqualToString theId]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Another approach is to implement the `isEqual` method in `Store` to compare IDs only.  Then construct a dummy `Store` object with the ID you're looking for and use `indexOfObject` or `containsObject`, referencing your dummy `Store` object.

Comment: I quote from the question: `I know I can do this using a for loop and break when found`. The only thing missing in your reply is the `break;` to not loop unnecessary. Thanks though.

Comment: @PaulPeelen -- Break is not needed since it returns from the loop.